# How to execute WinAppDriverUiRecorder

Tags: c#, unit-testing, user-interface, winappdriver

I want to try the tool called Ui Recorder which is included in the WinAppDriver. I opened the file WinAppDriverUIRecorder.sln in Visual Studio 2019. Then I chose the Debug Option to open this recorder. However during the execution I got the following error:

`System.DllNotFoundException: It was not possible to load DLL File UIXpathLib.dll.This module was not found`.

I was checking in the folder that I downloaded from Github and I could not find it. Could someone help to find a reason and solution why this is happening?.

Thank in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the latest binaries from the "releases" section. I'm using the version 1.0. The download link is given below. 
https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/releases/tag/UiR_v1.0-RC

Comment: Hi Naeem. Thanks for your help. Yes, you are right, the best way to retrieve the executable is through releases. Tks again